# Get grid location from click in Swift with Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, grid, location

I have a dynamically generated grid that can give me the location of the center of ones its tiles given the row and column with my gridPosition function, but I can't figure out the opposite. I am trying to keep everything dynamic so this will work on all screens and devices.

How do I get the row and column from the location? I tried reversing how I get the gridPosition but it is off by a lot. Is there an easier way to do this? or did I make an error?

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation


class Grid:SKSpriteNode {
var rows:Int!
var cols:Int!
var tileIsValid:[[Bool]]!
var blockSize:CGFloat!

convenience init(blockSize:CGFloat,rows:Int,cols:Int) {
    let texture = Grid.gridTexture(blockSize,rows: rows, cols:cols)
    self.init(texture: texture, color:SKColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    self.blockSize = blockSize
    self.rows = rows
    self.cols = cols

    self.tileIsValid = Array.init(count: rows, repeatedValue: Array.init(count: cols, repeatedValue: false))

}

override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

class func gridTexture(blockSize:CGFloat,rows:Int,cols:Int) -> SKTexture {
    // Add 1 to the height and width to ensure the borders are within the sprite
    let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(cols)*blockSize+1.0, height: CGFloat(rows)*blockSize+1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let offset:CGFloat = 0.5
    // Draw vertical lines
    for i in 0...cols {
        let x = CGFloat(i)*blockSize + offset
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: size.height))
    }
    // Draw horizontal lines
    for i in 0...rows {
        let y = CGFloat(i)*blockSize + offset
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: size.width, y: y))
    }
    SKColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1.0
    bezierPath.stroke()
    CGContextAddPath(context, bezierPath.CGPath)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return SKTexture(image: image)
}

// give row, col and get cgpoint of tile
func gridPosition(row:Int, col:Int) -> CGPoint {
    let offset = blockSize / 2.0 + 0.5
    let colsMiddle = (blockSize * (CGFloat(cols)) / 2.0)
    let tileWidth = (CGFloat(col) * blockSize)
    let x = tileWidth - colsMiddle + offset


    let rowsMiddle = ((blockSize * CGFloat(rows)) / 2.0)
    let gridHeightNum = CGFloat(rows - row - 1)
    let gridHeight = (gridHeightNum * blockSize)
    let y = gridHeight - rowsMiddle + offset
    return CGPoint(x:x, y:y)
}

func gridIsValid(location: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let offset = blockSize / 2.0 + 0.5
    let colsMiddle = (blockSize * (CGFloat(cols)) / 2.0)
    let midColCalc = location.x + colsMiddle - offset
    let midColCalc2 = midColCalc / blockSize
    let col = Int(round(abs(midColCalc2)))


    let rowsMiddle = ((blockSize * CGFloat(rows)) / 2.0)
    let midRowCalc = location.y + rowsMiddle - offset
    let midRowCalc2 = midRowCalc / blockSize
    let midRowCalc3 = midRowCalc2 + 1 + CGFloat(rows)
    let row = Int(round(abs(midRowCalc3)))

    print ("\(col) \(row)")

    return self.tileIsValid[col][row]

}
```